# Resumé – how to include grant awarded to my undergraduate project but is part of a bigger grant?

Tags: funding, cv, research-undergraduate

I am aware of similar questions, but they don’t really apply to my situation. I’m applying to graduate schools and I would like to list a grant I received as an undergraduate on my resumé.

The problem is, my grant (in the form of a stipend) is only part of a big NSF grant awarded to my PI and his project, and I’m working on this project. I have the NSF award number and the project name, but since (apparently) I don’t get all the grant (which is a great amount of money) but only a small part of it, how should I list it on my resume?

What I did was list it as “NSF Grant” with the award number, but how do I make it clear so that people won’t misunderstand?

Comment: Is what you received a subaward of some type under the PI's grant? Is the PI's grant one of the traditional undergraduate student training grants like an REU?

Comment: Were you involved in the writing of the grant proposal?

Comment: No I wasn't involved in the proposal writing; but the grant is a subaward of my PI's award. Yes, it's an REU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My immediate reaction is that if you weren't involved in the writing of the grant, you aren't responsible for the *awarding* of the grant; rather, you were *hired* to a position that happened to be funded by that grant. Therefore it would be misleading/unethical to list the grant on your CV/resumé, but you can and should list this **position**, along with your responsibilities, skills you learned, any results or publications, etc.

(Incidentally, it would be a terrible idea to list the full amount of your PI's grant. Not only is it unethical, but it would look laughable that an undergraduate had been awarded a six- or seven- or eight-figure grant. The result would be that the committee would view your entire application with suspicion.)

Comment: Note: I do not have much experience with subawards, so it is possible I have misunderstood the relation between the student's position and this award. I would welcome corrections if so.